# How to find this limit $\lim\limits_{(x,y) \to (1,1)} \frac{y-x^4}{y^3-x^4}$

Tags: calculus, limits, multivariable-calculus

How would I find this limit?

$$\lim_{(x,y) \to (1,1)}  \frac{y-x^4}{y^3-x^4}$$

Comment: Using L'Hôpital, if you come in parallel to the $y$-axis, you get $\frac13$. Parallel to the $x$-axis, you get $1$. There is no limit. The function is not continuous at $(1,1)$.

Comment: I want to find a path to prove it does not exist I tried $y=mx$ and $y=mx^4$ but I fail

Comment: Not along the $x$-axis, but parallel to it. @robjohn

Comment: @ThomasAndrews: fixed :-).

Answer (score 3):

Limit does not exist. Try path $y=1$ and $x=1$ you will get different limits.
Regarding your comment you cant choose $y=mx$ as path as it does not reach point $(1,1)$.

Comment: Unless $m=1$...

Answer (score 1):

This limit does not exist. Try the two trace to the point: x-axis and y-axis.